# How to hide using webdriver selenium in Chrome?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I want to hide using webdriver
In FireFox it looks:

```
option = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
option.set_preference('dom.webdriver.enabled', False)
```

So, i want know hot it make in Chrome? Is it possible?

Comment: Did you find how to do this in chrome? I have the same doubt

Answer (score 0):

You can set the window position outside your monitor, something like this

```py
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.set_window_position(-10000,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `headless` to `True`:

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.headless = True

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = 'chromedriver.exe', options=options)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

options.add_argument('headless')
options.add_argument('window-size=1920x1080')

driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver', chrome_options=options)
```